# Performance issues in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, compiler-construction

I have learnt that, code interpretation is much slower than executing a compiled code. But shell scripts are always interpreted. And many *nix software use shell scripts. So won't that lead to performance degradation?

Is there any new advancements for solving this? Like the bytecode formats followed by many new languages?

Comment: Consider learning `assembly` or `C` =)

Comment: Do you have a specific concern?  Or are you just trying to be as fast as possible?  Typically a shell script is calling compiled C tools to do most of its work, no?

Answer (score 2):

A typical shell script spends much more time running other programs than interpreting the script code.  Those programs are written in a compiled language if the performance is needed.  For example, `grep` is written in C.

Answer (score 0):

shell scripts typically evoke a wide range of binary programs written in assorted languages. 
scripts calling these external programs in loops and trees experience a great deal of fork() ing which creates alot of context switches, slowing down everything alot.

one way you can compensate for this is makeing your shell scripts take advantage of multiple cpus and multiple machines via ssh